# How to open ical event without downloading using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, icalendar

I am trying to implement a function where users will be able to open appointments/meetings on performing some action. I found it can be done using **ical**.

```
var icsMSG = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:-//Our Company//NONSGML v1.0//EN\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nUID:me@google.com\nDTSTAMP:20120315T170000Z\nATTENDEE;CN=My Self ;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:me@gmail.com\nORGANIZER;CN=Me:MAILTO::me@gmail.com\nDTSTART:" + msgData1 +"\nDTEND:" + msgData2 +"\nLOCATION:" + msgData3 + "\nSUMMARY:Our Meeting Office\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR";
window.open( "data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG));
```

But it is first downloading the ics file, and then only when a user clicks on the downloaded file, it will open the appointment. Instead of that, I want the appointment to be opened directly without downloading. Please help me with this.